# Swift structs: Protocol (w/asoc. types) v/s Composition

Tags: swift, struct, protocols, linear-algebra

I’m refactoring a Linear Algebra library. It includes a Vector, Matrix and Tensor structs. So far so good, but since the three of them are conceptually *Tensors*, they share a lot of properties and underlying behavior. Therefore, I’m trying a refactor to be able to share more code and tests between them.

But I’m fairly new to Swift, and I’m not sure if I should do it with Protocols:

- TensorProtocol with Associated Type (“T”).
- Extension over TensorProtocol which implements all the common behavior as the “default” for the protocol.
- Tensor, Matrix and Vector which conform to TensorProtocol.

The advantage of this approach is that common behavior is shared in one place, and can be overriden for customization.

The disadvantages are:

1. TensorProtocol doesn’t let me specify internal logic. I can only have public variables if I want to make the protocol public.
2. I can’t aggregate the structs for Testing, I think? Because Protocols with AT can’t be used as variable types.

Because of this I thought of a second option:

- TensorSkeleton struct, with all the behavior of a Tensor inside of a struct.
- TensorProtocol, which only defines the API of a Tensor.
- Tensor, Matrix and Vector, all of which contain a TensorSkeleton and use it to conform to the TensorProtocol.

This approach allows me to:

1. Reuse all of the Tensor logic for the three structs.
2. TensorSkeleton can have a finer design than a protocol. Since it’s a struct, it can have internal and private fields and functions.
3. Testing the TensorSkeleton is (at least for me) easier than it would be to test a Protocol. And by testing it, I’m giving guarantees over all of the structs that use it.

But it has two disadvantages:

1. It still doesn’t allow me to aggregate for Testing (same as the first approach), and...
2. This model clashes with me. I come from C#, where this would’ve been solved with abstract classes and class inheritance (Matrix : Tensor,  and such). Is my concern justified? I have never used a model where inherited traits were passed down with composition instead of class inheritance. 
   I know Linear Algebra objects are much better suited as structs, but I still have doubts about this design.

Thank you very much, and I’m sorry for the wall of text. Have a great day.